# slicing and dicing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I would like to reshape a data frame object in multiple steps by first removing the first several rows of data, second setting a new index, and then lastly choosing which columns to include.  The dataframe object is parsed from an excel file and includes header information that i would like to separate from the data frame values in the lower part of the sheet.  Any pointers to libraries and or specific components of libraries would be appreciated.  Links to documentation would be most helpful.

```
 excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\SBF\Desktop\LocalsOnly\SurfWrap\26_34.xlsx')
 df1 = excel_file.parse('WestBluff')
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried first bro

Comment: Please don't explain your code without showing your code.

Comment: Requests for resources (such as libraries and documentation) are off-topic.

Comment: You should provide a sample dataset at least